# jcarousel is not scrolling through images

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, jcarousel

i have a jcarousel gallery of images

but the jcarousel is not working at all it's not scrolling through images at all

this is my code :

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">  
    <?php foreach ($images as $image_item) : ?>
     <li><img src="<?php echo $image_item['Path']; ?>"/></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

and this is my css  :

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container {
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    height:250px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width:  500px;
    height: 250px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

and there is my js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({wrap:'circular'});
});
```

Comment: ... and what about the JavaScript?

Comment: i edited the post and added the js code

Comment: Well do you get any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Well I'll try to set up a jsfiddle - you realize that auto-scrolling is turned off by default, right?  You have to set "auto" to something other than zero if you want that behavior.

Comment: i don't want auto scrolling but the problem is even when i click the next and previous buttons the images don't scroll

Comment: @M.B.Asfoor - see my answer - your code is basically working just fine for me.

Comment: i think it's css problem more than code problem because when i disable my page css the carousel works correctly .

Comment: @M.B.Asfoor perhaps - if you [check the jsfiddle I set up](http://jsfiddle.net/kDNCb/1/) you can see that it works. I don't have fancy-looking buttons, but clicking "Prev" and "Next" do the right thing.

Comment: @Pointy thank you very match i figured out what the problem was and solved it . it appears that i forget to put rtl:1 for the carousel because my body is rtl and it was ltr it gave me alot of errors i will mark you answer as accepted answer thank you again

Comment: @M.B.Asfoor - ok well that's very nice!  You can add your own answer if you want to, and then other people may benefit from the work you've done :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your code is almost correct](http://jsfiddle.net/kDNCb/1/) — you just need to add "auto: 1" (or some other non-zero number of seconds) and it'll start auto-scrolling. If you don't want auto-scroll, you need to specify the "buttonNextHTML" and "buttonPrevHTML" parameters to get buttons.